# How to create inset border using border-image

Tags: css, image, border, border-image

I am trying to use border-image to create a custom border for images, but need the border to be inset as opposed to outside the image.

Here's what I have now: https://jsfiddle.net/kq69nxvn/

```
HTML: <p><img class="customBorder" src="http://lorempixel.com/640/480/" /></p>

CSS: img.customBorder {
  border-style: solid;
border-width: 5em;
-moz-border-image: url(http://despeaux.consulting/larryhooke/wp-content/uploads/sites/14/2017/02/imageBorder-draft1-black.png) 30 stretch;
-webkit-border-image: url(http://despeaux.consulting/larryhooke/wp-content/uploads/sites/14/2017/02/imageBorder-draft1-black.png) 30 stretch;
-o-border-image: url(http://despeaux.consulting/larryhooke/wp-content/uploads/sites/14/2017/02/imageBorder-draft1-black.png) 30 stretch;
border-image: url(http://despeaux.consulting/larryhooke/wp-content/uploads/sites/14/2017/02/imageBorder-draft1-black.png) 72 stretch;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about this? https://jsfiddle.net/mLerfzzr/

Comment: Or this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mWyjXv different method. .... can you clarify what you mean by inset ?

Comment: Thank you both Pangloss and GCyrillus -- that's exactly what I needed. I really appreciate the help.